# Quick Finder suddenly cannot find

Tags: qgis-plugins

[image]

Too bad the plugin is 'probably currently in use**d**' because it worked fine all last week and is a great productivity booster when it does work.

Does anybody have an idea why this happens?

Comment: Which version do you have? Have you just changed project?

Comment: Thanks Brad. The version is 2.4.0-Chugiak. No, the project's the same as last week. I suspect some update-activity over the weekend but can't get that verified.

Comment: Sorry, which version *of the plugin* do you have?

Comment: Version 3.2.5, authors Denis Rouzaud and Arnaud Morvan.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.